# Sort by last updated entry in descending order as default using react-bootstrap-table-next

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, user-interface, frontend

Sort by last updated entry in descending order as default.
I have tried the below code it's not working, can someone help me on this?

Initial code below it sorts the last updated date based on month not based on a year(since the listLastUpdated is sent as string)
Ex: when I sort 01-10-2022 is coming first than 11-10-2021 when u sort in ascending order
because dates are treated as strings rather than dates

```
listLastUpdated: (((new Date(updated_at).getMonth() > 8) ? (new Date(updated_at).getMonth() + 1) : ('0' + (new Date(updated_at).getMonth() + 1))) + '-' + ((new Date(updated_at).getDate() > 9) ? new Date(updated_at).getDate() : ('0' + new Date(updated_at).getDate())) + '-' + new Date(updated_at).getFullYear().toString().substr(-4))
```

```
{
          text: "LAST UPDATED",
          dataField: 'listLastUpdated',
          sort: true
}
```

I tried like below by referring https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/docs/column-props.html
Note : using react-bootstrap-table-next plugin for sorting

```
{
          text: "LAST UPDATED",
          dataField: 'listLastUpdated',
          sort: true,
          sortFunc: (a, b, order, dataField, rowA, rowB) => {
            if (order === 'asc') {
              return b - a;
            }
            return a - b; // desc
          }
        }
```