# How to convert string date to following date format dd-mm-yyyy as a object type in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, user-interface

How to convert string date to following date format dd-mm-yyyy as a object type in javascript

Ex:
var date='2021-02-23T10:08:44'
var convertedDate='02-23-2021'

The below code works and converts as string '02-23-2021', but because of this I am not able to sort it in UI according to the year,month and date since I am sending it as a string.

```
let convertedDate = (((date.getMonth() > 8) ? (date.getMonth() + 1) : ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1))) + '-' + ((date.getDate() > 9) ? date.getDate() : ('0' + date.getDate())) + '-' + date.getFullYear().toString().substr(-4));
```

Here I have more elaborated question:
[Sort by last updated entry in descending order as default using react-bootstrap-table-next](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66873635/sort-by-last-updated-entry-in-descending-order-as-default-using-react-bootstrap)

Comment: Why not keep the dates as Date objects in order to sort them and only turn them into a string when it comes to displaying them?

Comment: @ChrisG can you help me with example please ?

Comment: here I have more elaborated question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66873635/sort-by-last-updated-entry-in-descending-order-as-default-using-react-bootstrap

Comment: Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/kx3qyh9p/

Comment: I amended my answer, I hope it's what you want

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```js
var strDate = '2021-02-23T10:08:44'
var convertedDate = new Date(strDate).toLocaleDateString('US').replaceAll('/', '-')
console.log(convertedDate) // 2-23-2021
```

Comment: @userrj_vj_051620 I edited my answer, I didn't see quite well the format you wanted